# Enviroment variables in Vite + React coming back undefined

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, vite

I am trying to get some environment variables to work but for the life of me I can not...I have looked through a few SO answers and they all seem to point to how I have set things up.

Yet I keep getting undefined. This is how I am testing the variable.

```js
import {useState} from 'react'
import {FaCog} from 'react-icons/fa'

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [dealId, setDealId] = useState('')
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  // Counter
  const [count, setCounter] = useState(0)

  console.log('HOST:', import.meta.env.HOST) // returns undefined
```

This is my `.env` file, which is placed in the root

```bash
# .env
HOST=127.0.0.1:8000
```

This is my structure (removed node_modules) for ease

```
.
├── .env
├── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── src
│   ├── App.jsx
│   ├── favicon.svg
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── logo.svg
│   └── main.jsx
├── tailwind.config.js
└── vite.config.js
```

Where am I going wrong? I have restated the vite server many times already...i am stumped

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to prefix the name of your environment variables with `VITE_` if you want to expose the variables clientside.
Like this: `VITE_HOST` both in the `.env`-file and in the code. See the example below.

```
# .env
VITE_HOST=127.0.0.1:8000
```

```
// .js-file
console.log('HOST:', import.meta.env.VITE_HOST)
```

More about environment variables in Vite here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables

Comment: Thanks resolved this ages ago...but thanks for the input this will help others out.

Good to mention that this is only if you need to expose the variables client side.